# MS Access 2010 VBA: mysterious compile error on custom LostFocus sub

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In a data validation form, I have a subroutine checking previously-entered data on a LostFocus event by ensuring that the release time (TimeReleased in table; Me.txtTimeReleased on form) is after the capture time (ObservationTime in table; Me.txtObservationTime on form).  I'm using LostFocus rather than BeforeUpdate because the data were bulk-imported into the db and are now being error-checked.

My users keep getting a compile error (Compile Error: method or data member not found) upon tabbing out of the field this sub is attached to but I cannot reproduce the problem locally.  The error occurs on this line:

```
If (Me.txtTimeReleased) <= (Me.ObservationTime) Then
```

and the part highlighted is '.txtTimeReleased'

Full code block:

```
Private Sub txtTimeReleased_LostFocus()

Dim badData As Variant
Dim resp As Variant

'Also check that time released is after time captured
If Not IsNull(Me.txtObservationTime) And Not IsNull(Me.txtTimeReleased) Then
     If (Me.txtTimeReleased) <= (Me.ObservationTime) Then

         resp = MsgBox("Release time must be after capture time." & vbCrLf & "Please double check this field's value: is it correct?", _
                 vbYesNo + vbExclamation + vbDefaultButton2, "Release Time Before Capture Time")

         If resp <> vbYes Then badData = True

     End If
End If

If badData = True Then
     Me.cmbTaxonId.SetFocus 'set focus away so can set focus back
     With Me.txtTimeReleased
         .SetFocus
         .SelStart = 0
         .SelLength = 10
     End With
End If

End Sub
```

Other things to note:

- Both the table field and form control are formatted as 'Short Time' (24-hour time)
- There is an input mask on that form control for 24-hour time; I use input masks very rarely and thus aren't familiar with them--perhaps the input mask could be causing the problem?
- There are similar LostFocus subs on most of the other controls which do not produce this (or any other) error

Things I've tried:

- Checking spelling
- Fully decompling and recompiling the code: starting with shift, compact and repair with shift, open with /decompile flag while holding shift, compact and repair with shift, re-open with shift,  and finally compile (without error)
- Replacing the form in their database with one that works fine for me on the same data
- Google

Things that seem odd to me:

- I can't reproduce the error locally.
- The error is triggering on the second instance of
  Me.txtTimeReleased rather than the first: it has already passed a Not
  IsNull(Me.txtTimeReleased) check.
- The fact that it's a compile error: could that be masking something else?

Thanks for your time, and please let me know if there's any additional information that would be useful.  Any thoughts are most welcome!

Comment: What happens if you discard those parentheses? `If Me.txtTimeReleased <= Me.ObservationTime Then`

Comment: @HansUp Nothing locally, but I'll swap them out in the main db and see what happens.  You're right that they're not needed.

Comment: Have you tried using `.Value` instead of the default property?

Comment: @dwo I hadn't.  No change in my local copy but I'll put that on the list of things to try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the .mdb with the `/decompile` flag is one of the first things I would have suggested, but you said you already tried that.

Here's another undocumented trick to deal with "hidden" compile problems that get baked in by VBA behind the scenes:

First, make a backup copy of your .mdb just to be safe (this is, after all, an undocumented technique).

Then, save your form to a text file using SaveAsText:

```
SaveAsText acForm, "MyFormName", "C:\MyFormName.txt"
```

Finally, re-load your form using the equally undocumented LoadFromText:

```
LoadFromText acForm, "MyFormName", "C:\MyFormName.txt"
```

Compile.
Compact.
Repair.
Hope for the best.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You checked for Null txtObservationTime and txtTimeReleased, but compare then txtTimeReleased and ObservationTime. Maybe solution is:

```
If Not IsNull(Me.txtObservationTime) And Not IsNull(Me.txtTimeReleased) Then
     If (Me.txtTimeReleased) <= (Me.txtObservationTime) Then
```

Comment: Thanks for catching this!  That didn't solve the compile issue, but does solve another bug my users just ran into the other day.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use variables:

```
intThat = Me.txtTimeReleased 
If intThis <= intThat Then
```

Try using `!` instead of a dot:

```
intThat = Me!txtTimeReleased 
If intThis <= intThat Then
```

And now, the answer that worked for me last week:

1. Comment out the offending line.
2. Run a compile that is successful.
3. Restore the offending line.

The compile may work now.  Don't ask me why.

Comment: Well, I had another compile problem that was not solved this way once.  So it can't be Voodoo.  :-D